# Android HTTP Library to handle sessions, cookies, post/get, keep-alive and async

Tags: android, http, cookies, asynchronous

What HTTP library should I use as a core of my application ? 
Need to handle these:

- Cookies
- POST / GET
- Keep-Alive capability
- HTTP Sessions
- Asynchronous requests
- Stream compression (Gzip)

in API from Level 7 (So AndroidHttpClient can't be used)

Comment: Hi! Quick question, why can't HttpClient be used with api 7? I have programmed using HttpClient in Android 2.1 and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: AndroidHttpClient was added in API 8 as just another subclass of HttpClient with a specialized configuration. According to the Android docs it is "configured with reasonable default settings and registered schemes for Android"

Comment: @Otra: HttpClient is interface implemented in API v8 as AndroidHttpClient, so yes, I can create my own implementation, but I'm asking for mature tested library solution.

Comment: Ah, understood. I have never used AndroidHttpClient, I've only either implemented my own or used DefaultHttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite an old question, but I should provide up to date correct answer.

The final and best choice was probably **Android Async Http Client** from **James Smith (aka LoopJ)**

**Github:** https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http
**Website:** http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

**+ Feature HttpClient in version 4.2.3**
**+ Compatibility since API 1**

It's not very hard to use library **httpclientandroidlib** and build more up to date version of **loopj async http client**

For those who just want to use library, I provide my custom updated version (with latest 4.2.3 HttpClient)

**https://github.com/smarek/Android-Async-Http-Client-Updated**

Answer (score 0):

Android includes the apache HTTP library. See

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

for more. That should provide you with everything you need.

Comment: sorry, but you haven't answered my question. I have asked for library, not for set of classes. So solution could be AndroidHttpClient when I don't have API >= 8. See updated question please.

Comment: I did not suggest AndroidHttpClient. I suggested HttpClient: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html. That has been available since API 1. For an implementation to use directly, you can try http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: Yes, that is possible. `DefaulHttpClient` is usable